# Enum with array of string

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

I'm a newbie in Swift and I found on the internet a utiliy class to handle errors when I use Objective C classes from swift. Here the utility class, which is a enum:

```
enum Result<A> {
   case Success(Box<A>), Error(NSError)

   static func success(v: A) -> Result<A> {
      return .Success(Box(v))
   }

   static func error(e: NSError) -> Result<A> {
      return .Error(e)
   }
}

final class Box<A> {
   let value: A

   init(_ value: A) {
      self.value = value
   }
}
```

I have a function that returns an Array of strings of type result

```
func getFiles(account:DBAccount, curFolder:String) ->Result<[String]>{ ...}
```

Now how can I access the results in an easy way. A println on the console gives me (Enum Value).
I tried to get the results using the following:

```
let dicList = getFiles(account, currFolder)
switch dicList {
   case let .Success(aBox): results = aBox.value
   case let .Error(err): results = []
}
```

now the array results contains the data, but is there no easier way to access the results.

thanks
arnold